# Adding letters aren't working - Please let me know where I went wrong

Tags: python

for some reason, I can't add letters together.

```
word1 = int(input(""))
word2 = int(input(""))

result = word1 + word2
print(result)
```

Comment: `int()` will only work if they type numbers, not letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `int` when concatenating strings. Remove them

```
word1 = input("")
word2 = input("")

result = word1 + word2
print(result)
```

(+) is usually for numbers and , is usually for letters

Comment: What do you mean by ", is usually for letters"?

Comment: @Barmar yes I missed that’s . Will delete my comment